# Why aren't container comparison operators allocator agnostic?

Tags: c++, containers, comparison, allocator

The comparison operators for containers require a matching allocator type, e.g. see the [`std::vector` comparison operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp).

That doesn't appear necessary to me… intuitively, all the operator needs to do is to compare the sizes of the containers and their elements. It shouldn't matter where the memory they're stored in came from.

Is there a deeper reason for this or is it just because this was not considered a relevant use case?

Expected: `std::vector` (e.g.) comparison operators to be defined for dissimilar allocators, e.g. `std::allocator<int>` (LHS) and `std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<int>` (RHS).

Actual: `std::vector` comparison operators only declared for LHS and RHS with same allocator type, as per cppreference.com.

Comment: Because it would make little sense to compare things of different types. The template parameters are part of the type. (e.g. `std::vector<T, A>` is a distinct type of `std::vector<T, B>`)

Comment: I don't quite agree with @Fareanor. We're comparing thing with same semantic and only different implementations. Btw, I suspect that `pmr` has been designed with this idea in mind. I think that the issue might be to allow the compiler to compare efficiently the data, but I won't bet much on that...

Comment: @Oersted IMHO _"same semantic"_ is the point of templates, but still `MyClass<A>` and `MyClass<B>` will remain two separate and different types, despite having the same semantic.

Comment: I can't find anything in the standard. But I can think of something : allocators may align data differently in memory and I can imagine compare the operators can be optimized a lot if the alignments (and padding) of the object in both vectors line up.

Comment: Probably just nobody bothered. If we support different allocators, what about `vector<A> == vector<B>` if A is eq-comparable with B? Or `vector == array`? Where do we draw the line? You can always use `std::equal` to compare two ranges.

Comment: @Fareanor   The comparison operators are templates anyway, with their declarations in the form `template< class T, class Alloc > bool operator==( const std::vector<T, Alloc>& lhs, const std::vector<T, Alloc>& rhs )` (and defined accordingly).    They could just as easily have been declared in the form `template< class T, class Alloc1, class Alloc2> bool operator==( const std::vector<T, Alloc1>& lhs, const std::vector<T, Alloc2>& rhs )`  and defined in a way that ignores the two allocators.

Comment: My thoughts on this is that if you are comparing the vectors against each other, you might then decide you need to move an element from one vector to the other.  That operation may depend on the allocator

Comment: @Peter Of course ! My point was **not** to say that it could not have been done, but more about the meaning of that. [@HolyBlackCat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78114825/why-arent-container-comparison-operators-allocator-agnostic?noredirect=1#comment137713492_78114825) explains it much better than me :)

Comment: explicit is better than implicit. It is relatively easy to implement those comparisons, but would be difficult to opt out from them if they were present. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @NathanOliver   Comparison operators for `std::vector` accept `const` references, which nominally means that neither operand of a comparison expression is changed.   Moving an element between the two vectors would change both operands.

Comment: @Peter I'm not saying the operator would do it, I'm saying the programmer might.  Typically if you use a non-default allocator you have a reason to do so and moving an object from a vector with a custom allocator to one without may cause an issue.

Comment: actually one can have `a == b` is `true` and at the same time `a.get_allocator() == b.get_allocator()` is `false` (provided that allocator can be compared). If you stay within the same type, the comparison is allocator agnostic

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai  Allocators are typically stateless (the standard allocators certainly are) and stateless objects (if comparing them is appropriate) generally compare equal.

Comment: @Peter sure, but they are not required to be stateless afaik. And for a stateless one it would be simple to require `a1 == a2` for any two instances.

Comment: @Peter You might be conflating two concepts. The standard allocators have no mutable state (a given allocator and a copy of that allocator can be used interchangeably). But that doesn't mean that allocators of the same type are indistinguishable. Instances of `std::allocator<T>` are but instances of `std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<T>` aren't, this type's comparison operator compares the memory resources the allocators point to.

Answer (score 0):

I lived my entire professional life under the radar, never commented, never voted in forums, never asked questions. Made an account here recently to post an answer into a matter that affected me and others here quite personally, but had no reputation to do it. My searching for random opened questions that I could actually comprehend has brought me here.

Now, the more I think about an answer, the more I feel that your question is indeed quite fundamental, going to the essence of STL and that of other technologies. I am old enough to have lived through the beginnings of this industry and seen many of its convulsions. I think about all our struggles over the decades that have turned so religious, and about the moments in history where the industry has made some really bad turns. I believe the advent of STL in the late 90’s  was one such turn, at a time when C++ could have gone on a simpler and clearer path if, for example, it allowed Pascal-like functions-in-functions.

The most important struggle of all times is over memory management. What we are all trying to achieve is algorithms running over a liquid memory substrate. Some have determined that in order to get there, we would actually need new languages where memory is, by design, abstracted away from the algorithm e.g. C#, Java. While going down that path, the designers have broken the one thing that is paramount to many of us: the cohesion of structures. In languages like that, you are not even allowed entertain the idea of asking for offsetof(structure.field), and sizeof(structure) is a fiercely guarded secret. You are also not allowed to assume that in struct {SomeType a; SomeOtherType b;}, fields a and b are adjacent in a memory layout.

C++’s answer to this algorithm/allocation separation is STL. The algorithms of STL use container iterators abstracted away from the user’s elemental data types. Behind the scenes, containers are also detached from the underlying memory allocation. Since they need performance, algorithms can and need to exploit the properties (axioms) of the underlying allocators. What STL is trying to achieve, is to get the allocator to freely shift, grow, and shrink elements and ranges while the upper algorithm is running and as the iterators are iterating. An incredible level of sophistication stems from here. C++ is now having to import heavily from Algebra of Categories. Everything now has to be axiomatic and tractable. You replace good-old debugging with scientific proofing.

Allocator is not only an argument for the comparison operator, but for all operations. Let’s sample this for the index operator []... It too takes the allocator argument. So, perhaps moving elements around while iterating over their containers is possible. It’s unfinished business, though, and feels like a trap. Down that way, one would surely need to interop between STL and the rest of C++, just as per manged vs. unmanaged in C#. Also, let’s give this a thought: what are these && rvalue references all about, really? I see a trend for STL and BOOST to become a dotNET tucked-up in header-files.

Another reason for promoting allocators everywhere is the promise of better performance. Within the same allocator, pointers and references are totally comparable. So equivalence == can be tested at reference level without going into content.

Please note that I was faithfully trying to help and share a point of view. I am now going to brace myself for the barrage of down-votes that are sure to come. Regards.